# Why is my else if statement is not working?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
const yourIngredients = {

    'spice rack': 'cinnamon',
    'closet': 'flour',
    'cabinet': 'brown sugar',
    'fridge door': 'eggs',
    'closet shelf': 'chocolate chips',
    'lower cabinet': 'baking soda',
    'drawer': 'yeast',
    'cupboard': 'vanilla extract',
    'table': 'salt',
    'fridge': 'milk'
}

function bakingIngredients(ingredientYouNeed, locationsOfIngredients) {

  for (let location in yourIngredients){

    if (ingredientYouNeed === yourIngredients[location]){

       return `You found ${yourIngredients[location]} in the ${location}`;

    } else if(String(ingredientYouNeed) !== yourIngredients[location]) {

      return "oof, you ran out :(";/*not working*/

    }

  }

}

console.log(bakingIngredients('flour', yourIngredients)) //--> You found flour in the closet

console.log(bakingIngredients('brown sugar', yourIngredients)) //--> You found brown sugar in the cabinet

console.log(bakingIngredients('cream cheese', yourIngredients)) //--> oof, you ran out :( /*not working*/
```

Comment: What's "not working" about it?  What is the purpose of `String()` around your `ingredientYouNeed` variable?  What is the purpose of the second `if` in the first place, instead of just an `else`?

Comment: Please be more specific about the behavior you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

None of your examples should work because you're returning the value on first iteration, so the function can only check the first element (only `'spice rack'`).

The block saying that you've run out of an element should happen **after** you've iterated through all the locations and didn't find the element.

Like this:

```js
const yourIngredients = {
  'spice rack': 'cinnamon',
  'closet': 'flour',
  'cabinet': 'brown sugar',
  'fridge door': 'eggs',
  'closet shelf': 'chocolate chips',
  'lower cabinet': 'baking soda',
  'drawer': 'yeast',
  'cupboard': 'vanilla extract',
  'table': 'salt',
  'fridge': 'milk'
}

function bakingIngredients(ingredientYouNeed, locationsOfIngredients) {
  for (let location in yourIngredients) {
    if (ingredientYouNeed === yourIngredients[location]) {
      return `You found ${yourIngredients[location]} in the ${location}`;
    }
  }
  return "oof, you ran out :(";
}

console.log(bakingIngredients('flour', yourIngredients)) //--> You found flour in the closet
console.log(bakingIngredients('brown sugar', yourIngredients)) //--> You found brown sugar in the cabinet
console.log(bakingIngredients('cream cheese', yourIngredients)) //--> oof, you ran out :( /*not working*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying a short answer of how I would expect this code to work even though at the time of writing the details are somewhat unclear.

Your problem stems from your your loop inside `bakingIngredients` always returning on the first iteration. You need to move your second statement outside of the loop so it is only used as a fallback when all others fail, not if anyone fails.

```
function bakingIngredients(ingredientYouNeed, locationsOfIngredients) {

  for (let location in yourIngredients){

    if (ingredientYouNeed === yourIngredients[location]){

       return `You found ${yourIngredients[location]} in the ${location}`;

    }

  }

  return "oof, you ran out :(";/
}
```